# Custom UITableViewCell with round rect

Tags: iphone

I have created custom tableViewCell.My table is of grouped style.My custom tableViewCell is having background color.Problem is cells will come round rect but there is still some white color view backside of my cell.So how to create custom cell with round rect so that ican set background color and add multiline text.
  I tried creating background view of round rect.It worked.But i have to create one more view to add multiline text.Is there way to create cell with background color,multiline text and round rect's.

Comment: Please include a screen shot here, because it's really hard to tell exactly what you mean. UITableViewCells don't need to have anything special done to them to work in the grouped style, so please elaborate.

Comment: I agree.  I have 8 different answers for you, but I'm not sure which one matches your question.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, there may be a number of causes, and a number of solutions, but if you get the backgroundColor of your cell to [UIColor clearColor], and you set the opaque property to NO, the chances are you will get the look you are trying to achieve.